# Match string in file1 with string in file2

Tags: bash, awk, sed

```
my data examples are 
1.txt
MTQZ3CODT0SQKGE3QE6B | j t | j | t | 22312 | stimpy | EST | 8 | 20 | text | list | 0 | | 2002-08-22 13:07:05

2.txt
 MTQZ3CODT0SQKGE3QE6B | joe@example.com

desired output 
joe@example.com | j t | j | t | 22312 | stimpy | EST | 8 | 20 | text | list | 0 | | 2002-08-22 13:07:05
```

I suppose to match & replace 1st column from 1.txt
with 2nd column in 2.txt
so far i did try :

```
awk 'BEGIN { while((getline < "file2.txt") > 0) a[$1]=$3 } { $1 = a[$1] } 1' file1.txt
```

Its work well but after 12hours of running i just finalise only 1GB looks very slow

```
INFO: file1.txt=7GB  file2.txt=4GB my memory 16GB
```

I'm not sure what cause the slowly thing but i hope if there's another fast way then i'm using of awk
will be helpfull.
Thanks!!

Note: I'm running out of memory is there another way to do it
and that's to not have an array at all?
Also in my case lines are randomly and not in the same lines!

Comment: repeated reads of `file2.txt` would explain the 'slow' processing; preference would be a solution that scans each file a minimum number of times (eg, anubhava's answer that scans each file once; though you'll need to watch memory usage as storing all of `file2.txt` in memory could be an issue if you blow out the available memory on the host)

Comment: @markp-fuso i agree with you
the way to do it, is run through the file1, and search in file2 for the key, when it finds it it print and goes to the next line, then you reopen file2 and repeat the process
awk cannot seek so you are constantly reopening the file
there's other way and that's to not have an array at all

Comment: if both files are sorted on the first field you could use a merge join method (ie, read one line at a time from both files, joining the rows as you proceed); `join` may work for you (if the files are sorted)

Comment: did you try anubhava's suggested code (does a single pass through both files)? if so and it's not solving your issue then add a comment to his answer so he can respond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk -F ' *\\| *' -v OFS=' | ' '
FNR == NR {
   map[$1]=$2
   next
}
$1 in map {
   $1 = map[$1]
} 1' 2.txt 1.txt
```

```
joe@example.com | j t | j | t | 22312 | stimpy | EST | 8 | 20 | text | list | 0 |  | 2002-08-22 13:07:05
```

Comment: thanks for you help, however still the out memory problem awk repeat the file read cannot seek!
is there another way to do it and that's to not have an array at all?

Comment: It is a very simple associative array containing single string as key and value. My be try splitting `2.txt` file upfront

Answer (score 2):

```
$ join <(sort 2.txt) <(sort 1.txt) | cut -d' ' -f3-
joe@example.com | j t | j | t | 22312 | stimpy | EST | 8 | 20 | text | list | 0 | | 2002-08-22 13:07:05
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output including cases that this doesn't work for.